# Android: Error 10 Google Sign in Problem with Store version

Tags: android, kotlin, google-signin

I'm building a release apk to store. I'm testing Sign with Google before sending it to the store. It works fine. Sending apk to play store. Download the app from the store and test it. The store app isn't working I receive error 10.
What can be the cause of this?
The code used to sing-in:

```
 private val googleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient by lazy {
        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestIdToken(BuildConfig.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID)
            .build()
        GoogleSignIn.getClient(requireActivity(), gso)
    }
...
signWithGoogleButton.setOnClickListener {
googleSignInClient.signInIntent.let { signInIntent ->
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The store uses different sha1 key to sign apps in the store. You need to check if that SHA1 is added to your credentials in Google Cloud console